# Angular2 Animations :: Easings not working as expected

Tags: animation, angular

I'm working on a collapsable component, one that you can click to roll-up/down to show/hide details. The component is as follows:

```
// component.ts

import {Component, Directive, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {trigger, state, style, transition, animate} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
    selector: 'expandable',
    template: '<div *ngIf="isExpanded" @animate="'slide'"><ng-content></ng-content></div>',
    animations: [
        trigger('animate', [
            state('slide', style({ overflow: 'hidden', height: '*' })),
            transition('slide => void', [animate('200ms ease-out', style({ height: 0 }))]),
            transition('void => slide', [style({ height: 0 }), animate('200ms ease-out',  style({ height: '*' }))])
        ])
    ]
})
export class SimExpandable {

    private _expanded: boolean = false;

    @Input('expanded') set expanded(value: string | boolean) {
        this._expanded = (value === 'true' || value === true);
    }

    get isExpanded(): boolean { return this._expanded }

}
```

The component works fine, partially. The animations, however, are not perfect. I've configured the component to use `ease-out` animation but in reality, the component animates linearly.

I've tried using `ease-out`, `easeOut`, `ease-out-cubic`, `easeOutCubic`, `ease-in-out`, `easeInOut`, `bounce`, and a lot of other permutations but the component still animates linearly. I **REALLY** need to use `ease-out` for my component. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you added the [web-animations.js polyfill](https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js) ?

Comment: the angular2 docs state that you dont need to add it for common browsers.. im using chrome for testing.. but i can adding it explicitly..

Comment: no luck with that either.. =(

Answer (score 17):

> CSS properties transition and animation allow you to pick the easing
>   function. Unfortunately, they don’t support all easings and you must
>   specify the desired easing function yourself (as a Bezier curve).

[Easings.net](http://easings.net/)

It would seem that there are 4 default types of easing that should work.

- linear
- ease
- ease-in
- ease-out
- ease-in-out

These work directly, however the differences are subtle

For more effective types of easing, you have to use a bezier-curve which allows you to create your own easing. For example the below is "easeInOutBack"

```
cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)
```

When using with Angular animate function

```
animate("1500ms 2000ms cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)", style({transform: "translateX(-100%)"}))
```

You can navigate to this [bezier curver generator](http://cubic-bezier.com/) which should provide you with the ability to create your own easings.

Comment: Really nice! working in my project, but I use just one duration: transition('open=>close', animate('1000ms cubic-bezier(0.680, -0.550, 0.265, 1.550)')),

Answer (score -2):

Animate is no longer a part in angular/core.. so you have to import it, its part of the module ngAnimate .. so to use the $animate service you need to import js/lib/angular-animate.js libs.

```
bower install --save angular-animate
```

Comment: are you referring to Angular2 or the older Angular v1?

Comment: Im using the latest. and then in the css i use -enter and leave and there apply the ease-out stuff. like so https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate

Comment: Sorry my bad.. i was using the v1.5